# How to customize php built-in web server

Tags: php

How do I customize PHP's built-in webserver so that it automatically renders the index.php or index.html file in the directory where it's being redirected. It's equivalent in Apache is the directory index:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've already done an eyeball search and ctrl+f on php.ini for the word "directory" but no luck.
What file do I have to edit when I'm making use of PHP's built-in webserver?

Comment: ... PHP doesn't *have* a built-in web server...

Comment: Maybe he means the command line... but even then the question makes no sense.  I'm confused.

Comment: What about one in PHP 5.4? http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: I'm asking if its possible for php's built-in webserver to automatically render index.php or index.html files in a specific folder because it just displays a blank page whenever I do something like header('Location:folder/sub_folder')

Comment: @user225269 we are not clear on what you consider the "PHP's built-in webserver " to be?

Comment: It's the one linked by @PhpMyCoder php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php  the one that you run from the command line

Comment: Just when you thought they couldn't cram anymore crap in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new built in server is pretty bare bones, so lacks many of the features of Apache. By default it should automatically render the index.php or index.html, from the doco:

> If a URI request does not specify a file, then either index.php or
>   index.html in the given directory are returned.

The only way I've found that you could alter which page is used (i.e. to emulate changing the DirectoyIndex directive) would be to use a router script:

> If a PHP file is given on the command line when the web server is
>   started it is treated as a "router" script. The script is run at the
>   start of each HTTP request. If this script returns FALSE, then the
>   requested resource is returned as-is. Otherwise the script's output is
>   returned to the browser.

If you are at the point you need to mess around with the directory index, maybe it is time to use a proper web server?